# .net core 3. Unload assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I don't understand why in this situation context is not unload

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomAssemblyLoadContext context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
        Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"C:\Users\Greedy\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyApp.dll");
        context.Unload();
        
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            Console.WriteLine(asm.GetName().Name);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

But now context context is successfully unloaded.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomAssemblyLoadContext context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
        Load(context);
        context.Unload();
        
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            Console.WriteLine(asm.GetName().Name);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Load(CustomAssemblyLoadContext context)
    {
        Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"C:\Users\Greedy\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyApp.dll");
    }
```

Why? and how i can fix unload in first example?

Comment: What is `CustomAssemblyLoadContext`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `assembly` variable is holding a reference to your loaded DLL.

It works in the second example because you've declared `assembly` as a local variable of a method, so the variable goes out of scope when control flow leaves the method.

There are other caveats.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/load-unload#:%7E:text=To%20unload%20an%20assembly%20in,Unload%20method.).

Comment: Yes. I think too. And problem was in "Debug". 
-> Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034)